# Ответ на запрос об оплате php

Tags: php

Читаю документацию по реализации оплаты на сайте, и не понимаю, как реализовать ответ.

В документации написано:

> Скрипт должен отдать системе ответ со статусом 200 OK в заголовке и
>   словом SUCCESS.

После оплаты система перенаправляет на мой скрипт, например pay.php и передает различные параметры произведенной оплаты.

```
/pay.php?id?ID=54600817&TRANSACTION_ID=FF790...
```

Я эти параметры получаю, обрабатываю, понимаю, что все ок. Но как отдать ответ обратно, если все ок?

Comment: Например, командой `echo`.

Comment: А HTTP код как header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// ... обрабатываю, понимаю, что все ок. Но как отдать ответ обратно, если все ок?
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
echo "SUCCESS";
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает